# the "for" loop when sorting an array of integers using ONLY pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to figure out how the "for" loop works in a function that sorts an array of integers using only pointers, no indices. The following function accomplishes the task, but I don't understand what values are being compared in the statement "aptr1 < a + n - 1."  I understand this statement is used to scroll through the array and that a+n-1 is equivalent to &(a[n-1]) which points to a particular value in the array, but how does comparing values contained in the array accomplish the task of scrolling through the array the way indexes do?  Thanks for any your help!

btw- In the functions arguments *a points to an array of unsorted integers, and n holds the number of integers in the array.

```
void sort (int  *a, int  n)  
{  
    int  *aptr1, *aptr2, temp;  

for ( aptr1 = a;  aptr1 < a + n - 1;  ++aptr1 )  
     for ( aptr2 = aptr1 + 1;  aptr2 < a + n;  ++aptr2 )  
         if ( *aptr1 > *aptr2 ) {  
            temp = *aptr1;  
            *aptr1 = *aptr2;  
            *aptr2 = temp;  
       }  
}
```

Comment: `a + n - 1` is a pointer to the last element. The rest can be extrapolated from that.

Comment: if the value of the last element of the array is 2 and the value of aptr, which points to the first element of the array, is 3 then aptr is not less than the value of a+n-1 and the for loop is exited right?

Comment: In general, if you want to look at how to do an algorithm using pointers rather than indices, look at how C++ does it, since C++ iterators act like pointers.

Comment: *"I understand ... that `a+n-1` is equivalent to `(*a+n-1)`"*. No. It is equivalent to `&(a[n-1])`. `(*a+n-1)` is equivalent to `a[0] + n - 1`, while `*(a + n - 1)` (if you meant that) is equivalent to `a[n-1]`. Please note the differences between pointers, adresses and values pointed in all those cases.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Does that mean that the values being compared in the statement are address values?  I tried displaying the address values but the values weren't consistent with what would be needed to keep the for loop running.  i.e. the first set of address values in the for loop do not meet the requirement that aptr1<a+n-1

Comment: Yes. I don't know how have you tried to display those addresses, usually a debugger is the best choice, but they seem fine to me: https://ideone.com/YzRbGU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a+n-1` is not equivalent to `(*a+n-1)` . It is equivalent to `&a[n-1]`

To understand the loops just rewrite them the following way

```
for ( aptr1 = &a[0];  aptr1 < &a[n - 1];  ++aptr1 )  
     for ( aptr2 = &aptr1[1];  aptr2 < &a[n];  ++aptr2 )  
         if ( *aptr1 > *aptr2 ) {  
            temp = *aptr1;  
            *aptr1 = *aptr2;  
            *aptr2 = temp;  
       }
```

Though the code is not correct because you may not dereference the expression `( a + n )` nevertheless it helps to understood the expressions used in the original function.

Take into account that if n is equal to 0 then the original function is not correct due to the expression `a + n - 1`.

Comment: Is the (illegal) dereference actually performed or is the compiler allowed to interpret it as a (legal) pointer arithmetic operation resulting in a valid pointer (which a + n is)?

Comment: @Bob__ In my opinion there is a controversial description in the C Standard. On the one hand, there is written "If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply". That is there is said about constraints.

Comment: @Bob On the other hand, there is also written "Similarly, if the operand is the result of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator."  And nothing is said about constraints though there is present the word "smilarly".

Comment: Sorry Vlad, I edited my question a bit after clarification from bob about the mistake I had made.  I still don't understand what values are being compared in the statement   aptr1 < &a[n - 1].

Comment: @NotAWizard There are compared pointers that is the addresses they store. The pointer aptr1 can point any element of the array except the last element of the array. And indeed addresses of all elements of the array are less than the address of the last element.

Comment: That's helps a lot! Thank you!